# Change network settings using Python script

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, network-programming, subprocess

I am trying to **connect to a different WiFi network** via a Python script.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ that is running the latest version of Raspbian.

#### Adding a new network to the `wpa_supplicant.conf`

Given a different network with SSID `testing` and its password `testingPassword`, I learned that I can add a new network by executing the following in the terminal:

```
wpa_passphrase "testing" "testingPassword" | sudo tee -a /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf > /dev/null
```

So I figured I could use the subprocess library in python:

```
import subprocess

ssid = '"testing"'
passkey='"testingPassword"'

command = ["wpa_passphrase", ssid, passkey, "|", "sudo", "tee", "-a", 
"/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf", ">", "/dev/null"]

subprocess.run(command)
```

But all this does is output (in the terminal):

```
network={
ssid=""testing""
#psk=""testingPassword""
psk=3f446508c00cab57863ae62c8aaa505a4fae5d73461a0f10aee09988be8a2ae6
}


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

## Problem

Running the python script does not actually append the string to `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

## Solved

@DougieLawson solved this for me on the raspberry pi forum by using [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

See usage below:

```
import subprocess

ssid = "MickeyMouse"
passkey = "MinnieMouse"

p1 = subprocess.Popen(
    ["wpa_passphrase", ssid, passkey], 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)

p2 = subprocess.Popen(
    ["sudo", "tee", "a", "/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf", ">", "/dev/null"], 
    stdin=p1.stdout, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)

p1.stdout.close()  # Give p1 a SIGPIPE if p2 dies.

output,err = p2.communicate()
```